# How can I expand all lists in a row of lists at the same time?

Tags: powerquery, m

I would like to expand all of the lists in this table at once *without having to explicitly name (hard-code) each column*. I **do** want to assume that all columns have a list in the row. I also want to be able to apply the solution to a table with less or more columns than are in the example. The table might decrease or increase its number of columns and the columns' names might change, which is why I don't want to use explicit column names.

I've found a few threads about expanding multiple lists at once, at various forum sites, but they all address more than just doing what I describe above and have all confused me to one degree or another as I've tried to fit them to my need.

@MarcelBeug provides a detailed solution at [this site](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bf633836-b8cb-412c-a02b-c1199ace84d9/power-query-expand-multiple-lists-within-a-row-at-once?forum=powerquery) (as do other folks too). I'm using @MarcelBeug's function, and it works great; but I'd like to tailor it to just what I'm seeking, as mentioned above, and I'm having trouble doing that.

[image]

So how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to aggregate the `Table.ExpandListColumn` function across each column:

```
let
    Source = #table({"A", "B"}, {{ {1,2}, {3,4}} }),
    Expanded = List.Accumulate(
        Table.ColumnNames(Source), 
        Source, 
        (state, column) => Table.ExpandListColumn(state, column))
in
    Expanded
```

Comment: Please see [this follow-on question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44675481/how-can-i-expand-all-lists-in-a-row-of-lists-at-the-same-time-without-repeating) regarding your code above. Thanks.