# How can I expand all lists in a row of lists at the same time without repeating values?

Tags: powerquery, m

In response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44418244/how-can-i-expand-all-lists-in-a-row-of-lists-at-the-same-time) regarding how to expand all lists in a row of lists at the same time, @Carl Walsh kindly provided this succinct and helpful code:

```
let
Source = #table({"A", "B"}, {{ {1,2}, {3,4}} }),
Expanded = List.Accumulate(
    Table.ColumnNames(Source), 
    Source, 
    (state, column) => Table.ExpandListColumn(state, column))
in
Expanded
```

Which yields this:

[image]

I would like to get this result instead:

[image]

I don't want values repeated in previously processed columns as each follow-on column is processed.

Is there a simple modification to Carl's code that will get me there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not really simple, but effective: the code below combines the columns with adjusted code so the lists are zipped and the inner lists are transformed into records. Next the list column is expanded, resulting in a column with nested records which are subsequently expanded.

Unfortunately, you can't use combine columns with nested lists, so I created some dummy text columns first that I combined in order to generate the base code, which I subsequently adjusted and I removed the steps with the dummy columns.

```
let
    Source = #table({"A", "B"}, {{ {1,2}, {3,4}} }),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(Source,{"A", "B"}, each List.Transform(List.Zip(_), each Record.FromList(_,{"A","B"})),"Merged"),
    #"Expanded Merged" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Merged Columns", "Merged"),
    #"Expanded Merged1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Merged", "Merged", {"A", "B"}, {"A", "B"})
in
    #"Expanded Merged1"
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to learn a bit here, so if you wouldn't mind... would you please explain the usage of `_` in the combiner part: `each List.Transform(List.Zip(_), each Record.FromList(_,{"A","B"}))`? I'm pretty sure it serves as the "name" for the list, but I don't understand its usage beyond that. If you would explain it a bit and/or would direct me to more info about it so that I can learn more about it, I'll definitely appreciate it.

Comment: The _ is used in combination with keyword "each". The first _ (in "List.Zip") refers to the values in the columns that are being combined, i.e. the nested lists in your Source table in columns A and B.
The second _ belongs to each inner list of the zipped lists, i.e. {1,3} and {2,4}.
In general, "each"  is always pointing to the values in each table row or in each list item. In case of Table.CombineColumns it is only pointing to the values in the columns that are being combined.